# Multiple a number if variable is yes

Tags: php, if-statement, multiplication

I am trying to insert into a database the current rate multiplied by the mileage with an if statement. I need the mileage to be doubled if the journey is a return journey.

Tried some code which is posted below but struggling to make it work as it just takes the else line of code without considering if its no a return.

returntrip is posted from a form with the value of Y for yes, N for no.
I want amount to equal multiply the rate which is posted from the form by the mileage but the mileage could be exact as entered on the form if not a return journey or multiplied if a return journey.

```
 $tripis = $returntrip;
 if ($tripis="Y"){
     $checkmiles = $mileage * 2;
 } else { 
     $checkmiles = $mileage;
 }

 $amount = $rate * $checkmiles;
```

The above code just inserts the else regardless if the returntrip value is Y or N.

Comment: You are assigning `=` not comparing `==` in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement you are using a single equals operator `=`, which is assigning the string "Y" to the `$tripis` variable. To make a comparison between two values you need to use two equal symbols `==`.

```
$tripis = $returntrip;

if ($tripis == "Y"){
    $checkmiles = $mileage * 2;
}else { 
    $checkmiles = $mileage;
}

$amount = $rate * $checkmiles;
```